# Changing discriminator column to int in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

This is my situation, very much simplified.

My classes;

```
public class ClassBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClassMiddle1 : ClassBase
{

}

public class ClassMiddle2 : ClassBase
{
    public Guid Token { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : ClassMiddle1
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : ClassMiddle2
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

And my OnModelCreating;

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ClassBase>()
        .Map(m => {
            m.Properties(p => new { p.Id});
            m.ToTable("TableBase");
        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ClassMiddle1>()
        .Map<ClassMiddle1>(m =>
        {
            m.Properties(p => new { });
            m.ToTable("TableBase");
        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ClassMiddle2>()
        .Map<ClassMiddle2>(m =>
        {
            m.Properties(p => new { p.Token });
            m.ToTable("TableBase");
        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>()
        .Map<ClassA>(m =>
        {
            m.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.UserId,
                p.Username
            });
            m.ToTable("TableA");

        });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ClassB>()
        .Map<ClassB>(m =>
        {
            m.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.Username
            });
            m.ToTable("TableB");

        }).Property(p => p.Username).HasColumnName("User");

}
```

This works fine but the Discriminator column is by default Discriminator, NVARCHAR(128). I read that it is possible to define this column myself using something like below.

```
m.Requires("ClassType").HasValue(1);
```

I turned my possibilities inside out but all times running into a dead end. **Anyone having a suggestion how to do it?**

I will end with another question. As our hierarchy pretty much are as above but even more derivated classes like C, D, E, F and so on to... say P. We found out that EF are making this incredibly big database query (~150K). Anyone else ran into this scenario?

I am hoping with changing Discriminator to at least minimize this. By that I say we have a very neat class hierarchy but an ugly query set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late answer how the actual solution went. Only writing it down here because the documentation around this was not that easy to find.

My solution ended up like below...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassBase>()
        .Map(m => {
            ...
            m.Requires("Discriminator").HasValue(1)
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your "incredibly big database query": There are indeed [performance and query generation issues with TPT inheritance mapping](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/08/17/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx). There still doesn't seem to be a fix for those problems, only this vague announcement (August 2010):

> The good news is that we are working
>   on these issues so that EF no longer
>   generates unnecessary SQL. The bad
>   news is that it will take some time
>   before the fix is delivered in a
>   future release.

(Quote from the linked article above.)